# Is the official Javascript engine for weex on Android JSC or v8?

Tags: weex

According to the doc https://github.com/apache/incubator-weex, weex on android utilises chrome v8 engine which is quite true for versions <= 0.10. However, the latest apache/incubator-weex fork seems to be using JSC as the engine. Will JSC be the official engine in the future?